# PdfSharp: Why do I need to multiply positions and sizes by 1.25 to get the right result?

Tags: pdfsharp

I am evaluating PdfSharp to create PDF documents. While comparing it with MigraDoc I figured that I had to multiply each position (x, y) or size by 1.25 to get the intended result. For example if I set the page margins to 2 cm without the correction, I get margins of roughly 1.6 cm.

```
page.TrimMargins = new TrimMargins
{
    All = XUnit.FromCentimeter(2)
};
```

When I multiply 2 with 1.25 I get the intended 2 cm margins:

```
page.TrimMargins = new TrimMargins
{
    All = XUnit.FromCentimeter(2 * 1.25)
};
```

Same is with font sizes. I have to multiply the size by 1.25 to get the same size as MigraDoc or even Word would print.

My system does not have a custom scaling or a text size other than 100% by the way (my guess was this could be the cause).

Can someone explain what's going on here?

**Edit:**
With the help of TomasH I found out that when printing without auto scaling the sizing was perfect. PdfSharp obviously creates PDF documents too large. When doing the same with MigraDoc the PDF is also a bit too large as I found out, but only on a much smaller scale. The question that remains is why the document is too large and what MigraDoc does to correct the PDF size.

Here is my complete test code that only gives the correct positioning and sizing with the correction factor:

```
using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
{
    // Create an empty page size A4 with defined margins
    PdfPage page = CreatePage(document);
    using (XGraphics graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page))
    {
        const double sizeCorrectionFactor = 1.25;
        // Define the page margins. They must be multiplied by 1.25 to be correct!?
        page.TrimMargins = new TrimMargins
        {
            All = XUnit.FromCentimeter(2 * sizeCorrectionFactor)
        };

        // Draw a string. The font size needs to be multiplied by 1.25 to be correct!?
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        graphics.DrawRectangle(XPens.Black, XBrushes.White, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);
        graphics.DrawString("PdfSharp Measure Demo", new XFont("Verdana", 20 * sizeCorrectionFactor), XBrushes.Navy, x, y, XStringFormats.TopLeft);

        // Draw a rectangle. Position and size must be multiplied by 1.25 to be correct!?
        x = XUnit.FromCentimeter(2 * sizeCorrectionFactor);
        y = XUnit.FromCentimeter(2 * sizeCorrectionFactor);
        double width = XUnit.FromCentimeter(5 * sizeCorrectionFactor);
        double height = XUnit.FromCentimeter(5 * sizeCorrectionFactor);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(XPens.Red, XBrushes.Silver, x, y, width, height);
    }

    string pdfFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".pdf";
    document.Save(pdfFilePath);

    Process.Start(pdfFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Is it wrong in the PDF (e.g. measured with Adobe Reader) or is it wrong after printing? Print at 100% without auto-scaling and such. Make sure PDF and printer use same page size.

Comment: I printed at 100% and the sizing was perfect. Somehow PdfSharp creates PDF documents a too large as it seems. When doing the same with MigraDoc the PDF is also a bit too large as I found out, but only on a much smaller scale. need to figure out why that is the case and what MigraDoc does to correct the PDF size.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: I got the meaning of the (not well documented) `TrimMargins` property wrong. Setting the trim margins obviously adds the size of the margins to the width or height of the page. This means if trim margins are set, the page size is too large and usually gets scaled down when displaying or printing it. I set 2 cm for the trim margins, making the page obviously 1.25 times too large. The solution is to let all trim margins be 0 and account for any desired page margins in the printing code instead.